# Changing headers that IIS/ASP.NET sends. Side-effects?

Tags: http-headers

IIS / ASP.NET sends HTTP headers to identify itself by default.

```
Server               Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version  2.0
X-AspNet-Version     4.0.30319
X-Powered-By         ASP.NET
```

Is there any reason not to remove these? Considering the [ASP.NET vulnerabilities](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx) recently discovered, some people recommend changing the `Server` header to that of another server, such as Apache, to throw off scanners looking for affected websites. This seems like a good idea. Are there any unwanted side effects that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Andrew, but for practical purposes yes this is possible (see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/24885/how-to-remove-iis-asp-net-response-headers)) and I am not aware of any negative side-effects - I believe these exist purely for stat-gathering and "advertising" purposes and the ubiquitous "reserved for future use".

Comment: I neglected to be complete with my answer, and to note as annakata does that I am not aware of any negative side-effects, either!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, such tricks are not useful in the least. Spend your time making sure the server is actually secure, rather than wasting time on hacks of essentially no benefit whatsoever. There are plenty of other more reliable ways to know what operating system and web service a server is running.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll certainly do my best to ensure that the server is actually secure. So long as there are no negative side affects I'll throw off any automated scanners that read headers using this technique too.